# discord.py send BytesIO

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, bytesio

I am manipulating an image using Pillow, and then want to send it to Discord. My code: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/comebefupo.py

When using image.show(), the manipulated image is shown fine.

however, when I want to upload the image to Discord, the bot gets stuck and no error is thrown:

```py
got bytes from direct image string
got bytes from member/user pfp or str
opened image
opened draw
drew top text
drew bottom text
prepared buffer
prepared file
# Bot just gets stuck here, no errors
```

According to multiple sources ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/esmhxu/how_can_i_upload_a_pil_image_object_to_a_discord/ffb65qs?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), [2](https://gist.github.com/Gorialis/e89482310d74a90a946b44cf34009e88)), I am doing the right thing by saving the image into a BytesIO stream, and then using `seek(0)`.

According to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/api.html?highlight=send#discord.File.fp) for a discord.File, it takes a `io.BufferedIOBase` which is (I believe) I put in.

EDIT:
saving the image first, and then sending that works.

```py
# Return whole image object
return image

self.convert_bytes(image_bytes, top_text, bottom_text).save('image.png')
await ctx.send(file=discord.File('image.png'))
```

I have no clue why this works, and the other thing doesnt...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem last week, this was the code I used to send the image

```
with BytesIO() as image_binary:
             image.save(image_binary, 'PNG')
             image_binary.seek(0)
             await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fp=image_binary, filename='image.png'))
```

Comment: Definitely worked for me. By the way you made minor typo end of `'image.png))`

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer but it might help.

```py
image_file = discord.File(io.BytesIO(image_bytes.encode()),filename=f"{name}.png")
await ctx.send(file=image_file )
```