# Transform PIL image to PNG without saving it

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, python-imaging-library

It's me again

I've been having trouble with pillow in python, I want to convert a PIL image into a PNG, without saving it to my computer because I want to send it to discord:

```py
nums = Image.open('C:/path/nums.png','r')
background = Image.new('RGBA', (1000, 750), (255, 255, 255, 255))
background.paste(nums, (0,0))
background = background.save("1.png", "PNG")
picture = discord.File(background)
await channel.send(file=picture)
```

I also tried this:

```py
nums = Image.open('C:/path/nums.png','r')
background = Image.new('RGBA', (1000, 750), (255, 255, 255, 255))
background.paste(nums, (0,0))
buf = BytesIO()
background.tobytes('raw', "RGBA")
background.save(buf, format='PNG')
byte_nums = buf.getvalue()
picture = discord.File(byte_nums)
await channel.send(file=picture)
```

But it says:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I also tried a bunch of encoders but it doesn't seem to affect the output.
Every forum and documentation does it with jpeg, but I do need the alpha channel.

Thanks in advance, Noel.

Comment: Have you tried passing `buf` directly to `discord.File`?

Comment: @vivax yes, that doesn't work

Comment: try picture = discord.File(buf)

Comment: @pippo1980 I haven't tried but that is not saying what the image is to discord. You are just passing BytesIO()

Comment: Ok. Don’t know how discord works but bytesIO and buf are different types, and Image.open(bytes_nums) gives ValueError : embedded null byte while Image.open(buf) works so I though discord could work the same

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65496133/discord-py-send-bytesio