# Sending qr codes to discord user

Tags: python, file, discord, bots, qr-code

My discord bot creates qr-codes after a certain command. However I am unable to send this qr-code to the user as message:

```
import qrcode

def create_qr_code(string : str):

    qr = qrcode.make(string)
    return qr


# sending qr to user
qr_code = create_qr_code('some text')
# check if qr_code is None
print(qr_code)
await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fp=qr_code))
```

My `print` statement returns something like

`<qrcode.image.pil.PilImage object at 0x000001BD735FCF28>`,

which is fine and shows me that the creation of the qr code was successful.
I wonder why sending it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: cant you send a base64 encoded string to the channel instead? or as a blob

Comment: To err on the side of simplicity, why is having to delete temporary files an issue once they're uploaded...?

Comment: No that is not an issue, I thought using `save` funtion saves it permanently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found a working solution myself using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65496133/discord-py-send-bytesio) solution:

First of all I create a qr code and return this object

```
import qrcode

def create_qr_code(string : str):

    qr_code = qrcode.make(string)
    return qr_code
```

I can now use `BytesIO()` to send this qr code as binary file to discord:

```
import io

def some_other_function():

    qr_code = create_qr_code('my string')

    with io.BytesIO() as image_binary:
        qr_code.save(image_binary, 'PNG')
        image_binary.seek(0)
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fp=image_binary, filename='qr.png'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a package called [qrcode](https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/) and then use this code:

```
async def qrcode(self, ctx, *, url):
        qr = qrcode.QRCode(
            version=1,
            error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H,
            box_size=10,
            border=4,
        )
        qr.add_data(str(url))
        qr.make(fit=True)
        img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black",
                            back_color="white").convert('RGB')
        img.save('qrcode.png')
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File('qrcode.png'))
```

btw if you want to continue using [PyQRCode](https://pypi.org/project/PyQRCode/), looking at the pypi documentation it looks like you can do:

```
qr_code.png('code.png', scale=6, module_color=[0, 0, 0, 128], background=[0xff, 0xff, 0xcc])
```

To save it.

Comment: I edited my code, I am using `qrcode` now

Comment: I found a working solutiuon [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65496133/discord-py-send-bytesio)